# Unable to create a bar plot to visualize the results of the enrichment analysis using clusterProfiler

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm attempting to create a bar plot for the enrichment analysis using clusterProfiler, but I'm consistently encountering an error. All other plots are being generated without any issues. I'm following a tutorial provided on this webpage: https://yulab-smu.top/biomedical-knowledge-mining-book/enrichplot.html

```
# SET THE DESIRED ORGANISM HERE
organism = "org.Hs.eg.db"

#Prepare Input
# reading in data from deseq2
df = read.csv("res.degs.csv", header=TRUE)
names(df)[names(df) == "X"] <- "GeneSymbol"

# we want the log2 fold change 
original_gene_list <- df$log2FoldChange
# name the vector
names(original_gene_list) <- df$GeneSymbol
# omit any NA values 
gene_list<-na.omit(original_gene_list)
# sort the list in decreasing order (required for clusterProfiler)
gene_list = sort(gene_list, decreasing = TRUE)

gse <- gseGO(geneList=gene_list, 
             ont ="ALL", 
             keyType = "SYMBOL", 
             minGSSize = 3, 
             maxGSSize = 800, 
             pvalueCutoff = 0.05, 
             verbose = TRUE, 
             OrgDb = organism,
             pAdjustMethod = "BH")

head(gse)

barplot(gse, split = "ONTOLOGY")+facet_grid(ONTOLOGY~., scale = "free")+ggtitle("Barplot for GO")

dotplot(gse, showCategory=10, split=".sign") + facet_grid(.~.sign)
ridgeplot(gse, showCategory=4)
gseaplot2(gse, geneSetID = 1:4)
```

Error:

> barplot(gse, split = "ONTOLOGY")+facet_grid(ONTOLOGY~., scale = "free")+ggtitle("Barplot for GO")
> Error in barplot.default(gse, split = "ONTOLOGY") :
> 'height' must be a vector or a matrix

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.3.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Africa/Cairo
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rstudioapi_0.14             forcats_1.0.0              
 [3] clusterProfiler.dplyr_0.0.2 xlsx_0.6.5                 
 [5] wordcloud_2.6               RColorBrewer_1.1-3         
 [7] ggridges_0.5.4              pathview_1.40.0            
 [9] biomaRt_2.56.0              msigdbr_7.5.1              
[11] DOSE_3.26.1                 ggnewscale_0.4.9           
[13] fgsea_1.26.0                GSEABase_1.62.0            
[15] graph_1.78.0                annotate_1.78.0            
[17] XML_3.99-0.14               enrichplot_1.20.0          
[19] clusterProfiler_4.8.1       reshape2_1.4.4             
[21] stringr_1.5.0               dplyr_1.1.2                
[23] ggplot2_3.4.2               pheatmap_1.0.12            
[25] DESeq2_1.40.1               SummarizedExperiment_1.30.1
[27] MatrixGenerics_1.12.0       matrixStats_0.63.0         
[29] GenomicRanges_1.52.0        GenomeInfoDb_1.36.0        
[31] vsn_3.68.0                  org.Hs.eg.db_3.17.0        
[33] AnnotationDbi_1.62.1        IRanges_2.34.0             
[35] S4Vectors_0.38.1            Biobase_2.60.0             
[37] BiocGenerics_0.46.0         readr_2.1.4                

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] later_1.3.1             splines_4.3.0           bitops_1.0-7           
  [4] ggplotify_0.1.0         filelock_1.0.2          tibble_3.2.1           
  [7] polyclip_1.10-4         preprocessCore_1.62.1   lifecycle_1.0.3        
 [10] rprojroot_2.0.3         processx_3.8.1          lattice_0.21-8         
 [13] MASS_7.3-60             magrittr_2.0.3          limma_3.56.1           
 [16] remotes_2.4.2           httpuv_1.6.11           sessioninfo_1.2.2      
 [19] pkgbuild_1.4.0          cowplot_1.1.1           DBI_1.1.3              
 [22] pkgload_1.3.2           zlibbioc_1.46.0         purrr_1.0.1            
 [25] ggraph_2.1.0            RCurl_1.98-1.12         yulab.utils_0.0.6      
 [28] xlsxjars_0.6.1          tweenr_2.0.2            rappdirs_0.3.3         
 [31] GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.10 ggrepel_0.9.3           tidytree_0.4.2         
 [34] codetools_0.2-19        DelayedArray_0.26.3     xml2_1.3.4             
 [37] ggforce_0.4.1           tidyselect_1.2.0        aplot_0.1.10           
 [40] farver_2.1.1            viridis_0.6.3           BiocFileCache_2.8.0    
 [43] jsonlite_1.8.4          ellipsis_0.3.2          tidygraph_1.2.3        
 [46] tools_4.3.0             progress_1.2.2          treeio_1.24.0          
 [49] Rcpp_1.0.10             glue_1.6.2              gridExtra_2.3          
 [52] usethis_2.1.6           qvalue_2.32.0           withr_2.5.0            
 [55] BiocManager_1.30.20     fastmap_1.1.1           fansi_1.0.4            
 [58] callr_3.7.3             digest_0.6.31           mime_0.12              
 [61] R6_2.5.1                gridGraphics_0.5-1      colorspace_2.1-0       
 [64] GO.db_3.17.0            RSQLite_2.3.1           utf8_1.2.3             
 [67] tidyr_1.3.0             generics_0.1.3          data.table_1.14.8      
 [70] htmlwidgets_1.6.2       prettyunits_1.1.1       graphlayouts_1.0.0     
 [73] httr_1.4.6              S4Arrays_1.0.4          scatterpie_0.2.0       
 [76] pkgconfig_2.0.3         rJava_1.0-6             gtable_0.3.3           
 [79] blob_1.2.4              XVector_0.40.0          shadowtext_0.1.2       
 [82] htmltools_0.5.5         profvis_0.3.8           scales_1.2.1           
 [85] png_0.1-8               ggfun_0.0.9             tzdb_0.4.0             
 [88] nlme_3.1-162            curl_5.0.0              cachem_1.0.8           
 [91] parallel_4.3.0          miniUI_0.1.1.1          HDO.db_0.99.1          
 [94] desc_1.4.2              pillar_1.9.0            grid_4.3.0             
 [97] vctrs_0.6.2             urlchecker_1.0.1        promises_1.2.0.1       
[100] dbplyr_2.3.2            xtable_1.8-4            Rgraphviz_2.44.0       
[103] KEGGgraph_1.60.0        cli_3.6.1               locfit_1.5-9.7         
[106] compiler_4.3.0          rlang_1.1.1             crayon_1.5.2           
[109] labeling_0.4.2          ps_1.7.5                affy_1.78.0            
[112] plyr_1.8.8              fs_1.6.2                stringi_1.7.12         
[115] viridisLite_0.4.2       BiocParallel_1.34.2     babelgene_22.9         
[118] munsell_0.5.0           Biostrings_2.68.1       lazyeval_0.2.2         
[121] devtools_2.4.5          GOSemSim_2.26.0         Matrix_1.5-4.1         
[124] hms_1.1.3               patchwork_1.1.2         bit64_4.0.5            
[127] KEGGREST_1.40.0         shiny_1.7.4             igraph_1.4.3           
[130] memoise_2.0.1           affyio_1.70.0           ggtree_3.8.0           
[133] fastmatch_1.1-3         bit_4.0.5               downloader_0.4         
[136] ape_5.7-1               gson_0.1.0
```

here is the dput of my data:

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(GeneSymbol = c("AADACL3", "ADCY2", "ADGRG7", "AGR3", 
"AGXT", "ALDOB"), baseMean = c(1.05235591068955, 73.0482242356993, 
28.7309592989179, 777.856117021001, 15.6427712494994, 48.4332441791051
), log2FoldChange = c(2.50065318532507, -2.11320937760672, -2.81836101900824, 
-2.18781631056023, -2.0220216454214, -3.07875829787714), lfcSE = c(0.617603931898605, 
0.240745397032572, 0.361733427553782, 0.405454939802299, 0.32453811375843, 
0.282693336421694), stat = c(4.0489593025059, -8.77777686989715, 
-7.7912650707107, -5.39595426220979, -6.23045972013782, -10.8908060474568
), pvalue = c(5.14458890683536e-05, 1.66737654916863e-18, 6.63415713896086e-15, 
6.8160309507286e-08, 4.65068397802918e-10, 1.27506701279147e-27
), padj = c(0.000633345176049789, 5.93470261465896e-16, 1.23198221014601e-12, 
2.32589114746101e-06, 2.84446487601322e-08, 2.64544016586392e-24
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please post all `library` commands and ideally a `dput` of data for  a [mre]. `barplot` is a base R graphic that you are attempting to add ggplot layers. But [barpot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/barplot) does not have a *split* argument, so you may be using a different package for that method.

Comment: I updated the post. I hope this is helpful! Let me know if you have any other needed information.

Comment: Wow! You have a lot of packages in your session that most are not used in this posted code. Please put yourself in our shoes and run your code in an empty R environment with only the few `library` lines needed for a ***minimium*** reproducible example.

Comment: From your working link, it appears `barplot` derives from `enrichplot` package. In an empty R env, when you run this library line are there any warnings of overriding built-in methods? Are multiple options shown with `?barplot`? Try qualifying that method with double colon reference: `enrichplot::barplot(...)`. Your error raises from built-in `graphics::barplot(...)`.